# View changes its own frame when status bar gets hidden or shown

Tags: ios, layout, statusbar

I need to hide and show the status bar in my application, but when I do this with `setStatusBarHidden`, my navigation bar changes it's own frame (it moves up with 20pt). The content view changes it's own frame accordingly (it moves up with 20pt and increases own height). How can I change this behaviour and let my bar and content stay still while the status bar gets shown or hidden?

I've tried to observe `statusBarHidden` and forced change the frame of the nav bar and the content view, but I think this is not the best way for UI scaleability. Maybe there is a better way?

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"statusBarHidden"]){
        if ([change[NSKeyValueChangeNewKey]  isEqual: @(1)]){
            self.navigationBar.frame = ({CGRect newFrame = self.navigationBar.frame; newFrame.origin.y = 20; newFrame;});
        }else {
            self.navigationBar.frame = ({CGRect newFrame = self.navigationBar.frame; newFrame.origin.y = 20; newFrame;});
        }
    }
}
```

UPD

tried to use these settings in my content view controller:

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

...

```
-(BOOL)automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets{
    return NO;
}
-(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden{
    return NO;
}
-(CGSize)preferredContentSize {
    return CGSizeMake(320, 504);
}
```

doesn't helps at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I've found the best solution.
I will not hide the status bar with `setStatusBarHidden`
I will overlap it with new opaque window instead:

```
overlayWin = [[UIWindow alloc] init];
overlayWin.backgroundColor = NAVBAR_COLOR;
overlayWin.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar+1.f;
overlayWin.frame = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame;
overlayWin.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

No unwanted side effects with other view's layouts. Nice!

Comment: This is very dirty, and very crafty.

Comment: @user perhaps better solution would be to set frame of the main window (0,20,320,548) (roughly) and then change it in case of orientation changes